# Recognise Button Click from Instantiated Button - Hide Game Object in An Array

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, button, instantiation

Code is simply to generate buttons for a UI, and clicking the button hide the game object in the array, with only one visible at a time. At the moment I am struggling to get a button to work and change the game object that is visible, but have managed to get the object names in the array to replace the button text. Please Help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonListControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject ButtonTemplate;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] ApplianceList;
    GameObject ApplianceGUI;
    private int index;

    void Start()
    {
        ApplianceGUI = GameObject.Find("Canvas_GUI_ScrollList");
        ApplianceGUI.SetActive(false);

        // Finds GUI and turns off on run.

        foreach (GameObject Appliance in ApplianceList)
        {
            GameObject Button = Instantiate(ButtonTemplate) as GameObject;
            Button.GetComponent<ButtonListButton>().SetText(Appliance.name);
            Button.transform.SetParent(ButtonTemplate.transform.parent, false);

            Appliance.SetActive(false);

            if (ApplianceList[0])
                ApplianceList[0].SetActive(true);
            Button.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
  public void Option1Clicked()
    {
        foreach (GameObject Appliance in ApplianceList)
        {
            Appliance.SetActive(false);
            //Sets the current Game Object to false 

            ApplianceList[1].SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("New Appliance Chosen, Hiding Old model and displaying:", ApplianceList[1]);
        }
    }
       public void Option2Clicked()
    {
        foreach (GameObject Appliance in ApplianceList)
        {
            Appliance.SetActive(false);
            //Sets the current Game Object to false 

            ApplianceList[2].SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("New Appliance Chosen, Hiding Old model and displaying:", ApplianceList[2]);
        }
    }
       public void Option3Clicked()
    {
        foreach (GameObject Appliance in ApplianceList)
        {
            Appliance.SetActive(false);
            //Sets the current Game Object to false 

            ApplianceList[3].SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("New Appliance Chosen, Hiding Old model and displaying:", ApplianceList[3]);
        }
    }
       public void Option4Clicked()
    {
        foreach (GameObject Appliance in ApplianceList)
        {
            Appliance.SetActive(false);
            //Sets the current Game Object to false 

            ApplianceList[4].SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("New Appliance Chosen, Hiding Old model and displaying:", ApplianceList[4]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a GameObject, you make a copy from the template.
When you call `SetActive`, you call it on the template objects so it's probably applied to the prefab.

You should call that on the instantiated object instead, so you need another list to store every clone.

Also, you can simplify the code quite a bit, giving every button an Index (when it's instantiated) representing it's position in the list and a reference to the list itself.

This way, you can set the `OnClick` callback in the Inspector to the `ButtonListButton` own method instead of having to create `OptionNClicked` for each one.

```
public sealed class ButtonListControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] ApplianceList;

    // Hide every button except the one with the given index
    public void HideAllBut(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ApplianceList.Length; i++)
        {
            ApplianceList[i].SetActive(i == index);
        }
    }

}
public sealed class ButtonListButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int Index;
    [SerializeField]
    ButtonListControl List;

    // This asks the list to hide every button except for this one
    public void HideOthers()
    {
        List.HideAllBut(Index);
    }
}
```